# Trying to switch to Python, having problems

Tags: python, cgi

I'm a PHP programmer, but I want to learn Python. I'm a bit confused with how to actually execute a script. I've created test.py in my web server root, in the file I've written:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jon.cgi as cgi
import jon.fcgi as fcgi

print "Content-type: text/html"
print "hello world"
```

My server is running Litespeed, following the tutorial at: http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php?id=litespeed_wiki:python_fcgi I've installed Jon's CGI.

But when I navigate to the script in my browser it just prints the full code, as if it's not parsing it. Would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: This is not really a problem with the code. It is a problem with the webserver configuration, since it is not executing the code as a CGI script. The code here doesn't matter, and probably a better question for serverfault.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it was a server issue. Will try my luck at serverfault.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but may sidestep it: have you considered looking at full-featured Python web frameworks like Django?  The difference between coding in a proper Python framework and coding individual web pages in PHP is profound.

Comment: It may not helpful moving this to SF as it is probably better for the user to be looking into WSGI which is a better way to be writing Python webapps than CGI. This ties into using a framework like @AndrewG. states.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be easiest to start with WSGI under Apache using [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

A simple WSGI application looks like this:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Other Python frameworks build on top of WSGI. The quick start [installation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide) and [configuration](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) guides are worth a read. Packages are available for common Linux distros.

If you are interested in an alternative you might want to look at [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) which is an event-based server which has a different design.

As @cacahootie mentions below you should also look into web application frameworks for Python. These make writing apps that utilise WSGI much easier. [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is probably the most popular, but there are many [other options](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) with Python. My personal preference for a very light framework is [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), but it is not as comprehensive as Django.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Brian a bit.  For learning Python in a web application environment CherryPy is among the easiest ways to start.  It is a WSGI framework, but makes things so easy I don't know why you'd try to directly implement a WSGI app.  I know CGI is probably a more comfortable starting place, but frankly CherryPy (or some of the other more complex frameworks) make things so easy, and WSGI is the best way of deploying these apps.  WSGI is comparable to CGI - it is the interface that many frameworks may implement against.

[CherryPy Project Site](http://www.cherrypy.org/)

Hello World (from their homepage):

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: @Arran: Use CherryPy, or Django, or Pyramid, or Tornado, or Flask, or Bottle. Just use a web framework. Writing a new web app in Python _using CGI_ is simply a waste of time.